# The Modulus of all the roots of a Polynomial are equal to $1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, roots

> Suppose the real number $\lambda \in (0,1)$, and let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that all roots of the polynomial $$f\left ( x \right )=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\lambda^{k\left ( n-k \right )}x^{k}$$ have modulus equal to $1.$

The Putnam problem [2014 B4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054826/show-all-roots-of-sum-k-0n-2kn-k-xk-are-real-december-6-2014-putna?rq=1) is similar:  Show that for each positive integer $n,$ all the roots of the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{k(n-k)}x^k$ are real numbers.

Comment: The polynomial has "symmetrical" coefficents and can therefore be written as $g(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2})$ where $g$ is a polynomial. Then the problem is reduced to showing that $g$ has all its roots real and inside $[-1,1]$. Here techniques as in the Putnam question mentioned in the OP would probably be useful.

Comment: Also posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299304/the-modulus-of-a-polynomial-are-the-same-is-1

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Well, $x+1$ has “symmetric” coefficients but how to write it as a polynomial of $\dfrac12\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco This is a classical exercise : by induction on $n$, one shows that $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$ is of the form $Q_n(x+\frac{1}{x})$ where $Q_n$ is a uniquely defined polynomial of degree $n$. The exact term is "palindromic", by the way.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Isn't this true only for polynomials of even degree?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco  I just realized I forgot a scaling factor in my formula : I should have said $f(x)=(x^{\deg(f)})g(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2})$.

Comment: @Servaes This work in odd degree also : for example $x^1+\frac{1}{x^1}=Q_1(x+\frac{1}{x})$ where $Q_1(t)=t$, and $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=Q_3(x+\frac{1}{x})$ where $Q_3(t)=t^3-3t$ etc.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Neither $x^1+\frac{1}{x^1}$ nor $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}$ are polynomials though, and your scaling factor will yield polynomials of even degree.

Comment: @Servaes I don't understand your last comment at all. I never said $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$ was a polynomial, and gave you examples of odd degree : $Q_1$ and $Q_3$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy To get back to the original point; what do you mean by "symmetrical"? How would you write $f(x)=x+1$ as $f(x)=x^{\deg(f)}g(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}2)$?

Comment: @Servaes $f$ is palindromic when $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ with $a_k=a_{n-k}$ for every $k$. You're right though, my decomposition works only for even $n$ (though $g$ may be of any degree). And I got my formula wrong again : should be $f(x)=x^{\frac{\deg(f)}{2}}g(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2})$ $f(x)=x^{\deg(f)}g(\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2})$

Comment: I think this is answered on MO. Is there a need to put a summary here?..

Answer (score 4):

The following solution is taken from [The Modulus of a Polynomial are the Same](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1615959p12833777) on AoPS. For other solutions see [A family of polynomials whose zeros all lie on the unit circle](https://mathoverflow.net/q/299304/116247) on Math Overflow.

The idea is to derive a recursion formula for
$$
f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\lambda^{k(n-k)} z^k 
$$
and prove the statement by induction. $\lambda$ is a fixed real number in the interval $(0, 1)$.

$f_0(z) = 1$ and $f_1(z) = 1+z$ surely have only roots of modulus one.

Now assume that $n \ge 1$ and all roots of $f_n$ have modulus one. Using the recurrence formula for binomial coefficients
$$
 \binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}
$$
one gets
$$
 f_{n+1}(z) = f_n(\lambda z) +  \lambda^n z f_n(\frac{z}{\lambda}) \, .
$$
Now let $z^*$ be a zero of $f_{n+1}$. We have to show that $|z^*| = 1$.
From the above recurrence formula we get that
$$
 f_n(\lambda z^*) = -  \lambda^n z^* f_n(\frac{z^*}{\lambda})
$$
Note that $f_n(\frac{z^*}{\lambda})$ cannot be zero: Otherwise both $\lambda z^*$ and $\frac{z^*}{\lambda}$ would have modulus one, which is not possible.

Denoting the roots of $f_n$ with $z_1, \ldots z_n$ we have $f_n(z) = (z-z_1) \cdots (z-z_n)$ so that
$$
 z^* = - \frac{f_n(\lambda z^*)}{\lambda^n f_n(\frac{z^*}{\lambda})}
= - \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\lambda z^* - z_k}{z^* - \lambda z_k}
$$
and therefore
$$ \tag{*}
 |z^*| = \prod_{k=1}^n \left |\frac{\lambda z^* - z_k}{z^* - \lambda z_k} \right | \, .
$$
An elementary calculation (using $|z_k|=1$ for all $k$) shows that
$$
|\lambda z^* - z_k|^2 - |z^* - \lambda z_k|^2 = (1 - \lambda^2)(1 - |z^*|^2) \, .
$$

It follows that if $|z^*| < 1$ then all factors on the right-hand side of $(*)$ are larger than one, and if $|z^*| > 1$ then all factors on the right-hand side of $(*)$ are less than one. So both cases lead to a contradiction, and the only possibility is that $|z^*| = 1$. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score -3):

Write the above polynomial in the form:     $a+bx+cx^2$... and observe that if we put $f(x)=0$ it is same as putting $x^k f(1/x)=0$ {property of binomial coefficients and the power of lambda} conclude that if $x$ is a root  then $1/x$ is also has the same modulus. Hence $|x|=1$